# Erro ao declarar vetor de JTextField na classe

Tags: java, array, escopo-de-variáveis

Bom, gostaria de armazenar todos os meus `JTextField` em um array, porém, quando defino o vetor, recebo o seguinte erro: `llegal forward reference`. Segue a baixo o código onde defino o array.

```
private JTextField campos[] = {campoNome, campoUsuario};
```

Sei que poderia substituir pelo `ArrayList`, porém, gostaria de saber por qual motivo o erro foi gerado.

Comment: Você já definiu os campos dessas variaveis? Adicione o restante do código na pergunta.

Comment: O problema era exatamente este, acabei me esquecendo que dentro da minha classe os componentes Swing estão sendo declarados apenas no final dela.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`llegal forward reference` ocorre quando você tenta utilizar uma variável antes da mesma ter sido declarada ou inicializada. Ou seja, você está tentando utilizar uma variável que ainda nem existe. Este erro também pode ocorrer se tentar acessar um método de um objeto não declarado.

Possível causa desse erro no seu código pode ser devido a esta linha mencionada na pergunta estar anterior a inicialização e declaração das duas variáveis que você está adicionando no array. Algo que pode estar assim no seu código:

```
private JTextField campos[] = {campoNome, campoUsuario};
private JTextField campoNome, campoUsuario;
```

Repare que você declara os campos após criar o array, essa operação não é possivel pois naquele contexto elas ainda não existem. O problema é resolvido corrigindo o contexto, neste caso, declarando as variáveis antes de adicionar no array:

```
private JTextField campoNome, campoUsuario;
private JTextField[] campos = {campoNome, campoUsuario};
```

Lembrando que neste caso não ocorrerá mais o erro `llegal forward reference` pois os campos foram declarados antes de adicionados ao array, logo, eles já existem naquele contexto, mesmo não tendo sido inicializados ainda.

---

## Referências:

- [Restrictions on the use of Fields during Initialization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.2.3)
- [Ilegal Forward Error Reference Em Java](http://javaconceptoftheday.com/illegal-forward-reference-error-java/)

Answer (score -1):

Você esqueceu de dar um new no array:

```
JTextField campos[] = new JTextField[]{campoNome, campoUsuario};
```

Comment: Não é esse o motivo do erro.